# Keyboard on MSI Laptop automatically presses Tab

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Been finding anywhere but I don't have an answer to this problem. My laptop is experiencing "ghosting keyboard" in which it will press the `"TAB"` key. Pressing the `"ALT"` key stops it but after a while, maybe presses a few keys, it will return back on pressing the `"TAB"`key. I confirmed it only affects the laptop keyboard (PS/2 Keyboard in the Device Manager) when I uninstall it and using an external driver. Also, without the internal keyboard I can't connect to WIFI using FN+F8. Any help are appreciated.

Tried:

1. Reinstalling OS
2. Uninstalling Keyboard Driver
3. Changing to External Keyboard
4. BIOS Setups (No Keyboard related options)

and none worked.

Comment: Sounds like the keyboard may be marginal/failing/shorted; you may want to have that checked and/or replaced.

Comment: Darn... I have a gut for that too. It will be hard for a newly graduate for me thou. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highly likely to be a physical issue, rather than software. Laptop keyboards have a habit of becoming slightly dislodged enough to activate a key, usually one near the edge like `tab`. Often pressing a nearby key is enough to reseat the keyboard and temporarily remove the problem.

It's usually not hard to reseat the keyboard, assuming the keyboard is physically distinct from the laptop body (which it usually is with these symptoms). You need to locate the screws that are holding the keyboard down. They're usually under a plastic panel or otherwise hidden. Either try to find a repair guide for your laptop, or just try prying parts up to see if you can locate the screws. It's usually pretty obvious. Once the screws are revealed, simply unscrew them and carefully hinge the keyboard out. It'll be connected with some sort of ribbon cable. It's best if you detach the cable, but note that it's probably retained by a clamp on the socket, so be sure to release the clamp first.

Give the keyboard a twist, then plug it back in and test. Clean the mounting surfaces, then reassemble everything and re-test.